# VBA - sumifs in for loop - is there a more efficient way?

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I am trying to build a macro that calculates several sumifs, looking for conditions on a different worksheet. This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub SumPerYear()

Dim NoClients As Long
NoClients = Worksheets("Temp").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row - 1

Sheets("Temp").Activate

For i = 2 To NoClients + 1

    'Fill 2015 € in column E
    Cells(i, 5).Value2 = Application.SumIfs(Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("I:I"), _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("A:A"), 2015, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("D:D"), Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & i).Value2, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("C:C"), True)

    'Fill 2015 # in column F
    Cells(i, 6).Value2 = Application.CountIfs( _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("A:A"), 2015, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("D:D"), Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & i).Value2, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("C:C"), True)

    'Fill 2016 € in column G
    Cells(i, 7).Value2 = Application.SumIfs(Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("I:I"), _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("A:A"), 2016, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("D:D"), Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & i).Value2, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("C:C"), True)

    'Fill 2016 # in column H
    Cells(i, 8).Value2 = Application.CountIfs( _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("A:A"), 2016, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("D:D"), Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & i).Value2, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("C:C"), True)

    'Fill 2017 € in column I
    Cells(i, 9).Value2 = Application.SumIfs(Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("I:I"), _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("A:A"), 2017, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("D:D"), Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & i).Value2, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("C:C"), True)

    'Fill 2017 # in column J
    Cells(i, 10).Value2 = Application.CountIfs( _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("A:A"), 2017, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("D:D"), Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & i).Value2, _
        Worksheets("Q ALL").Range("C:C"), True)

    'Fill Tot € in column K
    Cells(i, 11).Value2 = Cells(i, 5) + Cells(i, 7) + Cells(i, 9)

    'Fill Tot # in column L
    Cells(i, 12).Value2 = Cells(i, 6) + Cells(i, 8) + Cells(i, 10)

Next i

End Sub
```

This code works, but because there are thousands of records, it takes a long time to complete. Is there a way to make this more efficient/faster?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: dont use the loop function -its  take so much of time to complete

Comment: So how can I do this differently then? What would you suggest?

Comment: Why are you not entering the SUMIF's directly into  row2 and then just copying them down?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Application methods work too slow on big count of cells, so you should write some code, that's not so nice and simple as yours.
Main idea is catched here:

```
Dim arrA as Variant 'change Variant to your type
Dim arrCD as Variant
Dim arr as Variant
Dim i as long
Dim k as integer
Dim NoClients As Long
NoClients = Worksheets("Temp").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row - 1

'assign Ranges to arrays
'we can't assign non-contiguous range, so we create two arrays
arrA = Range("A:A")
arrCD = Range("C:D")
ReDim arr(UBound(arrA), 3)
ReDim outArr(NoClients, 5 to 10)
'loop and fill third merged array
For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
    arr(i, 0) = arrA(i, 1)
    arr(i, 1) = arrCD(i, 1)
    arr(i, 2) = arrCD(i, 2)
Next i

'the rest of code You just loop through
For k = 2 To NoClients + 1 'get client
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'count summuries for him
        if (arr(i,0) = 2016) and (arr(i,1) = true) and (arr(i,2) = _
            Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & k).Value2) then
            'sumifs replacement
            outArr(k, 5) = outArr(k, 5)  + Worksheets("Q ALL").Cells(1+i, "I").Value2
            'countifs replacement
            outArr(k, 6) = outArr(k, 6) + 1 
        end if
    Next i
Next k

Worksheets("Temp").Range("A2").Value2 = outArr 'prints array on sheet with top left corner at A2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand you create a new array in your solution (arr), does this make the sumifs calculate faster? Could you give a small example of what the sumif should look like in the for loop?

Comment: @Geert I had misunderstood your task in some details, so code idea was changed a little bit.

Comment: We loop through clients list, for each client we calculate summaries based on data array, and these summuries put into outArr 2-dimension array, where first dimension is client number, second is data storage. Second dimension named (5 to 10) for better understanding meaning of indexes - they are equal to corresponding column number. Last string is a good trick for printing arrays. I believe it would work better, because any calculations, even lot of them, very much faster in memory than in sheet.